# Retrieving last portion of string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

Say I have a string `"like_this_string"` and I want to separate it into two parts: `"like_this"` and `"string"`.  So I can do this

```
first, last = "like_this_string".something
first == "like_this" # true
last == "string" # true
```

So the `last` part is always the `string` after the last `"_"` and the `first` part is always the `string` before the last `"_"`.  I would prefer a more efficient way of doing this than a combination of string to array, get last item, and then rejoin array (e.g. `split`, `pop`,  `join`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd do using [`String#rpartition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-rpartition)

```
first, _, last = "like_this_string".rpartition("_")
first # => "like_this"
last # => "string"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
((first, last)) = "like_this_string".scan(/(.*)_(.*)/)
first # => "like_this"
last  # => "string"
```

Comment: your regexp looks really stressed out `o_o`

Answer (score 2):

```
first, last = s[0..(ix=s.rindex("_"))-1], s[ix+1..-1]
```

(Really the same as using `rpartition`, I know... But piling on the possibilities is a Ruby tradition.)

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out one more way:

```
*first, last = "like_this_string".split('_')
first = first.join('_')

first #=> "like_this"
last  #=> "string"
```